# Scripting Eclipse Java Debugger?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, scripting

When using `gdb` to debug there are a [couple](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python.html) [of ways](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Break-Commands.html) to automate the actions performed when a break point is hit.  This is good for cases where I only have compiled code with debug symbols, not source code.  It is also nice when I want to instrument something interactively without relying on code reloading to insert print statements.

Is there a way to do this with the Eclipse debugger and Java code?  All I need is a way to print objects and variables and then continue from the breakpoint.

Comment: Can't you just hover over the object in question and inspect it? There's also a "variables" view for the debug perspective, right for this purpose. You can even change values on the run, within their scope.

Comment: Yes but doing that manually is slow and tedious when I can automate it.  Also, then the history of values is in my head instead of in the console.

Comment: Then what's the difference with logging?

Comment: I can "instrument something interactively without relying on code reloading".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject code using conditional breakpoints.

In this example the breakpoint never suspends because of `return false;`, but always print the absolut path of a file-variable named "file"!
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize that this could be arbitrary code.

Comment: Interesting. Can't wait to try that stuff out!